# Updating SQL Server with Checkbox Status

Tags: php, checkbox

I have page that pulls checkbox status from a SQL server, see code:

```
while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    echo "<form>";
    echo "<tr>"
        $checked = $row2['has_loan'] == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : '';
        $checked2 = $row2['has_telephone'] == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : ''; 
        $checked3 = $row2['has_remote'] == 1 ? "checked='checked'" : ''; 
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=loan $checked></td>"; 
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=telephone $checked2></td>";
        echo "<td><input type=checkbox name=remote $checked3></td>";
        echo "<td><input class=form-control id=input-Default type=submit name=recordupdate value=Update></td>";
    echo "</tr>"
    echo "</form>";
    sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt2);
?>
```

When the checkbox is ticked / unticked on screen I have a button which runs an update query on my database.

See code:

```
if(isset($_POST['recordupdate'])){
    $sup_code = $_POST['psupcode'];
    $checked = ($data['checkinsat'] == '1') ? 'checked' : '';
    if (!empty($_POST['loan'])) {
        $truel = 1;
    }else {
        $truel = 0;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['telephone'])) {
        $truet = 1;
    }else {
        $truet = 0;
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['remote'])) {
        $truer = 1;
    }else {
        $truer = 0;
    }

    $updateQuery = "UPDATE table
SET has_loan='$truel', has_telephone='$truet',has_remote='$truer'
WHERE sup_code='$_POST[psupcode]'";
sqlsrv_query( $conn, $updateQuery );
}
```

My code doesn't work and constantly updates with a value of '0'

Comment: I guess the problem is in your html code. Attributr value.

Comment: will this push either 1 or 0 via values? I can make the boxes appear checked by the data that's in the database but as soon as I update the tickbox on screen I fear the value isn't being passed.

Comment: If box is not checked the value is not posted. If this is all your html code then I dont' see 'psupcode' value

Comment: Sorry this is just snippet of code:

Comment: did you try to catch sql errors

Comment: Yea, this isn't SQL error..

I am strugging passing 1 if checked and 0 if not checked to POST method.

Comment: OK. $checked = $row2['has_loan'] == 1 ? "checked" : '';

Comment: so apply this to the function awaiting POST method? sorry :(

Comment: Does yor form has action="url" and method="POST"

Comment: it does yes, problem I have is on page if I tick the box and leave the other box unticked it should post both values to the function 1 and 0

Comment: If box is not checked the value is not posted.

Comment: <input type='checkbox' name='loan' $checked> add single guotes for all html attributes

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple form

```
<form action="pageb.php" method="POST">

    <input type='checkbox' name='telephone' value='1' checked/>

    <input type='checkbox' name='telephone1' value='1' />

    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="submit" >
</form>
```

And php

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    if (isset($_POST['telephone'])) {
        $truel = $_POST['telephone'];
}else {
    $truel = 0;
}
if (isset($_POST['telephone1'])) {
    $truela = $_POST['telephone1'];
}else {
    $truela = 0;
}
echo $truel;
echo '<br>'.$truela;
}
```